# Why Serilog LogContext lost properties during lifecycle?

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core-mvc, serilog

In a .NET Core MVC web application I have integrated Serilog as a logging system. In a custom Sink I'm logging every level to an API. Here I need some properties such as username. Because these properties are not always available. So when a view is opening a lot of informations logs happens and at a few log events the properties are available, but I should need them at every log event.

I'm pushing the properties in a AsyncActionFilter which is added to MvcOptions. Also tried to set it as an attribute on the HomeController. During lifecycle they have been popped from the LogContext. I'm also using a LogContextMiddleware to push some properties, but as described earlier I can't place some properties at this place.

Serilog configuration

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.PasSink(new SerLogServiceClient.SerLogServiceClient(new SerLogServiceClientOptions()))
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .CreateLogger();
```

LogContextFilter

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddMvcOptions(mo =>
        {
            mo.Filters.Add(typeof(LogContextFilter));
        });

 public class LogContextFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public LogContextFilterAttribute() : base(typeof(LogContextFilter))
    {
    }
}

public class LogContextFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public LogContextFilter()
    {
    }

    #region Implementation of IAsyncActionFilter

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        LogContext.Push(
            new PropertyEnricher("UserCode",
                context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ToString().StartsWith("UserCode"))?.Value),
            new PropertyEnricher("Test", "Will this go through?"));
        {
            await next.Invoke();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Serilog Sink

```
public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        var logMessage = logEvent.RenderMessage();
        //Console.WriteLine("Testing from PasSink. Whoop whoop! " + logMessage);

        try
        {
            if (logEvent.Level.ToString() == "Error")
            {
                var task = _serLogClient.Log.CreateLog(LogContent(logEvent.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "UserCode").Value.AsString(),
                    logMessage, logEvent.Level.ToString(), logEvent.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "TraceIdentifier").Value.AsString(), logEvent.Timestamp));

                //httpClient.PutAsync(_pasUrl, BuildJsonContent(logEvent.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "UserName").Value.ToString(),
                //    logEvent.Level.ToString()));

                logContent.ttLog.Clear();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //httpClient = new HttpClient();
            logContent.ttLog.Clear();
        }
    }
```

So I would like to have all properties at all log events. So maybe the mvc filter is not the correct place to push the properties to the context. But then what would be a good way to do this?